# Recursive relation-Theta notation

Tags: asymptotics, recursion

Consider the recursive relation:

$$T(n)=T(an)+T((1-a)n)+cn$$

where $0<a<1$ and $c>0$ are constants(independent of $n$).Show that $T(n)=\Theta(n \lg n)$

That's what I have tried:

We suppose that $T(n)=\Theta(n \lg n)$.

So, $\exists c_1,c_2>0$ and $n_0 \geq 1$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0$:

$$c_1 n \lg n \leq T(n) \leq c_2 n \lg n$$

Suppose that the guess stands also for $an,(1-a)n$.

Then:

$$c_1 a n \lg {(an)} \leq T(an) \leq c_2 an \lg {(an)}$$

$$c_1 (1-a) n \lg {((1-a)n)} \leq T((1-a)n) \leq c_2 (1-a)n \lg {((1-a)n)}$$

Therefore:

$$T(n) \leq \lg (n) c_2 n+c_2 a n \lg( a)+c_2 (1-a)n \lg (1-a)+cn \leq c_2 n \lg n \\ \text{ if } c_2 \leq \frac{c}{\lg(1-a)-a \lg \left (\frac{a}{1-a} \right )}$$

Respectively,we show that $T(n) \geq c_1 n \lg n$.

Could you tell me if it is right?

Is there a better way to show it?